# good/simple asp.net mvc application with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, sample

Where can i find a good/simple asp.net mvc application with fluent nhibernate? Any suggestion..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I wrote a [sample ASP.NET MVC application](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/aspnet-mvc/62-how-we-do-aspnet-mvc.html) which uses [FluentNHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) among other open source frameworks. The [source code](http://github.com/darind/samplemvc) is available on [github](http://github.com).

---

As requested in the comments section I've tried to summarize the important parts of setting FluentNhibernate with ASP.NET MVC:

Start by defining your model:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

Then the repository that will allow you to access the model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IUsersRepository
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetUsers();
    User Get(int id);
    void Delete(int id);
    int Save(User user);
    void Update(User user);
}
```

Then implement this repository:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Spring.Data.NHibernate.Generic.Support;

public class SqlUsersRepository : HibernateDaoSupport, IUsersRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return HibernateTemplate.LoadAll<User>();
    }

    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return HibernateTemplate.Get<User>(id);
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        HibernateTemplate.Delete(new User { Id = id });
    }

    public int Save(User user)
    {
        return (int)HibernateTemplate.Save(user);
    }

    public void Update(User user)
    {
        HibernateTemplate.Update(user);
    }
}
```

So far no FluentNHibernate specific parts. Let's define the mapping now:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("users");
        Id(x => x.Id, "usr_id");
        Map(x => x.FirstName, "usr_firstname");
        Map(x => x.LastName, "usr_lastname");
        Map(x => x.Age, "usr_age");
    }
}
```

And a Spring.NET session factory which uses SQLite but you could adapt as necessary:

```
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using Spring.Data.NHibernate;

public class FluentSessionFactory : LocalSessionFactoryObject
{
    private readonly string _dataFile;
    public FluentSessionFactory(string dataFile)
    {
        _dataFile = dataFile;
    }

    protected override ISessionFactory NewSessionFactory(Configuration config)
    {
        return Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(
                SQLiteConfiguration
                    .Standard
                    .UsingFile(_dataFile)
                    .ProxyFactoryFactory<ProxyFactoryFactory>()
            ).Mappings(
                m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>()
            ).BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Next we define a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUsersRepository _repository;
    public HomeController(IUsersRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_repository.GetUsers());
    }
}
```

Once we have all this in place we need to plumb the pieces together. As we are using Spring.NET we need to provide a custom controller factory:

```
public class SpringControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private static readonly IApplicationContext _springContext = ContextRegistry.GetContext();

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType != null)
        {
            var objectsOfType = _springContext.GetObjectsOfType(controllerType);
            if (objectsOfType.Count > 0)
            {
                return (IController)objectsOfType.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().First<DictionaryEntry>().Value;
            }
        }
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

Next comes web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="~/Config/springContext.xml"/>
    </context>
  </spring>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And finally the springContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">

  <object
    id="siteRoot"
    type="System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment, System.Web"
    factory-method="get_ApplicationPhysicalPath" />

  <object
    id="dataFile"
    type="System.IO.Path, mscorlib"
    factory-method="Combine">
    <constructor-arg name="path1" ref="siteRoot" />
    <constructor-arg name="path2" value="App_Data\data.db3" />
  </object>

  <object id="sessionFactory" type="AppName.Business.Repositories.FluentSessionFactory, AppName">
    <constructor-arg name="dataFile" ref="dataFile" />
  </object>

  <object id="sqlUsersRepository"
        type="AppName.Business.Repositories.SqlUsersRepository, AppName"
        singleton="false">
    <property name="SessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </object>

  <object id="home"
          type="AppName.Controllers.HomeController, AppName"
          singleton="false">
    <constructor-arg name="repository" ref="sqlUsersRepository" />
  </object>

</objects>
```

Comment: @darin i am using asp.net mvc 1.0

Comment: Sorry, my sample project works with VS2010, ASP.NET MVC 2.0. But the `FluentNHibernate` part could be reused as it is not specific to ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @Darin you r my savior thanks a lot man.... Its guys like you make this forum so special...

Comment: @Darin, your `SqlUsersRepository` methods can be generalised to a `HibernateRepository<T>`, where `SqlUsersRepository : HibernateRepository<User>` and likewise for other repo's.

Answer (score 4):

The orchard cms project uses fluent nhibernate.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Aim kai i downloaded it but i couldn't open the project file instead i got the error `this project type is not supported by this installation`

Comment: I'm not sure Orchard is very simple either. It's a good project, but it's not meant to be a demo app for NHibernate.

Comment: @Richard can you suggest me a sample which uses fluent nhibernate?

Comment: I guess some builds are okay and others are not. I managed to get it to build and run fine but I downloaded a version from last week - I guess its luck as it is being developed at the moment..

Comment: @Richard - its pretty well organised - and yes its not a demo for fluent nhibernate itself - but it is an mvc app that uses fluent nhibernate - thats why I suggested it. :)

Comment: Jason Dentler has a series of articles as well.. http://jasondentler.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-using-the-n-stack-part-1/

But Fluent Nhibernate 1.1. has come out more recently so not sure how current this is - maybe I should get my act together and write one up! :)

Comment: @Aim kai you're right. And it's the only app that I could think of. I just think it's a bit big to be a good example for NHibernate. @Pandiya Chendur, I can't think of a good example. Sorry for not being more helpful.